# Change nullability add primary key in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there are more terse way of writing (SQL server 2008)

```
alter table newclaims
alter column id int not null
go

alter table newclaims
add primary key(id)
```

the table is very large and this will have to make two passes over it and I'd like to know if I can change the nullability and add the primary key all in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for alter table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) suggests that you cannot both alter a column and add a constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name 
{ 
    ALTER COLUMN column_name 
    { 
        ...
    }    
    | ADD 
    { 
        ...
    } [ ,...n ]
```

Comment: completely unrelated but by you posting that I a light bulb went on for me understanding how to read that documentation.  You posting that little snippet there really helped me out on something completely unrelated